# How do you run a wordpress multisite locally?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to run a Wordpress MultiSite config locally using MAMP.

I copied the database and php files.

Then I change the main domain to `localhost:8888` and turned off subdomains:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost:8888');
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
```

I kept getting an error "Cannot connect to database".

When I went to localhost:8888/wp-admin I got a more detailed error, that my domain couldn't be find in `new2_wp_blogs`. So I went into the database and switched all the sites' domains to `localhost:8888` and the paths to the previous subdomains.

I also went into `wp_options` and changed `siteurl` and `home` to `http://localhost:8888`

Now when I go to `localhost:8888` the primary site works.

When I go to my first subsite site, I get redirected to `localhost/<nameofsite>`

When I go to `localhost:8888/wp-admin` I get redirected to:

`http://localhost:8888/%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20%20Use%20of%20undefined%20constant%20PWP_NAME%20-%20assumed%20'PWP_NAME'%20in%20%3Cb%3E/Users/anatoliyzaslavskiy/Sites/even-wp/wp-content/mu-plugins/mu-plugin.php%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E101%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%20/%3Ehttp://localhost:8888/wp-login.php?wpe-login=PWP_NAME`

Comment: So you already have a working site, and now want to migrate it to localhost?

Comment: @omerFarooq yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

A easy workaround is creating entries in your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) (for windows:  `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, for linux: `/etc/hosts`). For that, you choose a domain name which is not using a real top level domain, e.g. wordpress.local and add a list of multisite examples in your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1  wordpress.local
127.0.0.1  www.wordpress.local
127.0.0.1  test.wordpress.local
127.0.0.1  example.wordpress.local
127.0.0.1  more.wordpress.local
```

Now you can use `wordpress.local` for your multisite domain. Of course you need to configure your apache to handle these hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a live website and just want to create a sandbox version on localhost, then instead of manually migrating the site you can use plugins like [duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) which takes care of all the migration issues and gives you a nice installer to use.

While duplicator doesn't support multi site yet but here is another plugin that has support for multisite https://wordpress.org/plugins/ns-cloner-site-copier/